# iteration over non-sequence error with python web form

Tags: python, sqlite, cgi

Trying to teach myself Python. I've got a simple web app that takes the value of a form field, assigns it to a variable called "new_quote", and sticks that into a "content" field in a SQLite table.

When I hit the submit button on the web form, I'm getting a TypeError...

```
<type 'exceptions.TypeError'>: iteration over non-sequence 
      args = ('iteration over non-sequence',) 
      message = 'iteration over non-sequence'
```

It doesn't like the line below, but I'm not sure where to go from here.

```
for each_item in new_quote:
```

The CGI script for adding the quote to the DB is reproduced below. Any advice would be appreciated.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sqlite3
import cgi

import cgitb
cgitb.enable()

# This code takes the content of the form and assigns it to a   variable called new_quotes.

form = cgi.FieldStorage()
new_quote = form.value[(0)]

# Items from new_quotes are pushed into the DB in the code below.

for each_item in new_quote:

    connection = sqlite3.connect("quotes.sqlite")
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    content = new_quote[each_item].content
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO quotes(content) VALUES (?)")
    connection.commit()
    connection.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to iterate over the object itself, which is returning the error. You want to iterate over the list inside the object,

Comment: Ok thanks for the tip. I take that to mean specifying a particular instance of the object "new_quote". I amended the for loop to look like this... `for each_item in new_quote.new_quote:` Now I'm getting this error <type 'exceptions.AttributeError'>: MiniFieldStorage instance has no attribute 'new_quote'

Comment: Actually figured it out just a moment ago. Thanks for your tip!